# Convert boolean to text

Tags: if-statement, boolean, openoffice-calc

This seems like a simple question but i cannot find the answer anywhere. I have a spreadsheet with one column containing boolean values TRUE or FALSE, in the formula field they appear as =TRUE() or =FALSE(). If i convert them to text, they display as 1 or 0 but in the formula field they still appear as =TRUE() or =FALSE().

What i want to do is convert them all to text 1 or 0. Then i can use a IF statement on them in another field.

Alternatively, how can i use an IF statement on a boolean value???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell you want to say TRUE or FALSE should have this in it:

```
    =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("1",A1)),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

If the cell "A1" has a 1 in it, put TRUE... otherwise FALSE